# The solution curve of the differential equation $(x dx + y dy )\sqrt{x^2 +y^2} = (x dy - y dx) \sqrt{1-x^2 - y^2}$ is

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

The solution curve of the differential equation  is

$$(x dx + y dy )\sqrt{x^2 +y^2} = (x dy - y dx) \sqrt{1-x^2 - y^2}$$

I have substituted $$\cases{x=r \cos(\theta) \\ y =r \sin(\theta )}$$ but couldn't find the answer after solving it.
Help plz.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. It is encouraged to learn MathJax typesetting which is broadly speaking the "math-syntax" of $\LaTeX$. I helped you with doing that in this question, but in the long run you are expected to learn do so yourself.

Comment: [Here's a tutorial in MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 2):

An easy method to solve the ODE :

[image]

The constant $c$ has to be determined depending of the boundary condition. For some favorable boundary condition, it might be possible to reduce the implicit equation to a simpler explicit solution.

Since the boundary condition is missing in the wording of the question, one cannot go further.

Answer (score 0):

As you suggested, try $x=r(\phi)\cos\phi$, $y=r(\phi)\sin\phi$.
Then
$$xx'+yy'={1\over2}(r^2)'=r r'$$
and
$$xy'-yx'=r\cos\phi(r'\sin\phi+r\cos\phi)-r\sin\phi(r'\cos\phi-r\sin\phi)=r^2\ .$$
The given equation therefore transforms into
$$r r'\>r=r^2\sqrt{1-r^2}\ ,$$
or
$${r'\over\sqrt{1-r^2}}=1\ .$$
This is formally satisfied by the functions $$r(\phi)=\sin(\phi-\phi_0)\ ,$$ but you have to discuss the range of validity of this formula.

Comment: the answer is a circle of radius 1/2 and paint through origin. But I can't get it

Comment: @Lewis: No, the answer isn't a circle, but a family of curves because no boundary condition is specified in the wording of the question. The answer could be a circle for a particular condition to be specified.